# GMock and Gtest support for Windows 10 Universal platform

Tags: c++, win-universal-app, googletest, windows-10-universal, googlemock

Is GTest and Gmock testing frameworks supported for Windows 10 Universal Platform?

I looked into the Google Test repository in github https://github.com/google/googletest. It says it supports Windows mobile, but couldn't find anything relevant to this platform.

Any suggestions or pointers would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the library, yes it supports Windows Mobile but in the original, Windows Mobile 5, 6 meaning, no UWP support.